# App service takes too long to show up after publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

We have an .NET MVC web application deployed as an Azure app service. When we need to recompile and republish it, it takes almost 5 minutes before it comes back up, triggering website down email alerts.

The same app when deployed on local IIS/Windows 10 does not take more than 10 seconds to show up after recompile.

Not sure what could be causing this. Or what we could do to speed it up after re-publish.

**EDIT 1:** To publish the app we're using the Publish feature in VS2017 and using the publish profile from Azure app service.

[image: source of publish profile]

**EDIT 2** There was no difference after adding a staging deployment slot based on an answer below. Currently it's on S1 plan:

[image]

Comment: Azure App Service supports many publishing methods, so edit your question to include details on how you published your web app there.

Comment: Also, details of the size and capacity of the App Service plan is important - are you attempting to compare a B1 instance (1.75GB RAM, 1 Core) with a developer workstation (16-32GB RAM, 4+ Cores)? Have you already got multiple applications running on there?

Comment: Further to that, what do the Availability and Performance graphs under "Diagnose and Solve Problems" look like during app start-up - you should see options around CPU and Memory for your application, as well as options to dig into things like "Web App Slow" and similar.

Comment: for faster startup time of MVC apps on Azure App Services, you just need to precompile the views, so App services don't have to do that for every view that is needed at the time of the request. Add this to the MSBuild arguments and you'll have an ASP.NET MVC that will start up faster and every new page will load faster. 
`/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:UseMerge=true /p:SingleAssemblyName=AppCode` for mo detail you could refer this [link](https://blog.deltacode.be/2017/01/08/fix-slow-startup-of-asp-net-mvc-5-on-azure-app-services/)

Comment: @LexLi publishing using the publish profile downloaded from Azure app service. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the lack of details, one thing you can do is use Deployment slots. When it's ready in the slot, you can swap and your downtime / cold start will be almost zero.

Comment: Note that slots are only available in "Standard, Premium, or Isolated App Service plan tier", https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots Of course, users lower tiers shouldn't expect zero downtime.

Comment: Upgraded from Standard app service plan to Premium P2V2. That reduced the time considerably.